# SourceTree and GitHub: unable to pull / push after reseting to a previous commit

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

I messed my repository while trying to resolve conflicts. Everything was quite OK (I'm getting familiar with Git) but things got bad when I tried to reset the current branch to a previous commit (not knowing exactly what I was doing, I admit). In SourceTree, I now have 2 commits to Pull from GitHub and 10 commits to Push. When I tried to Pull, I got this:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin

git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false pull --no-commit origin master
From https://github.com/JnLlnd/CSVBuddy
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD


error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    TEST-TheBeatles-Tab (1).txt
    TEST-TheBeatles-Tab-EXPORT (1).txt
    TEST-TheBeatles-Tab-EXPORT.txt
    html-doc/img/review2_5_CSV Buddy_award.png
    icon/csvbuddy-16x16.png
    icon/csvbuddy-32x32.png
Please move or remove them before you can merge.

Aborting
```

I moved the 6 files and tried to Pull again. It seems to work (no error message). However, I still have the indication that there are 2 Pull to do.

If I try to Push the 10 commits, I get this error message:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin master:master
Pushing to https://github.com/JnLlnd/CSVBuddy

To https://github.com/JnLlnd/CSVBuddy 
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/JnLlnd/CSVBuddy'

hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Hum... I think I'm not that familiar with Git ;-) What should I do?

Comment: OK. Think I got it. I still had 2 conflicts to resolve before I can Pull / Push as desired. 

I will answer my own question after the 8 hours delay StackOverflow is making for new users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Think I got it. I still had 2 conflicts to resolve before I can Pull / Push as desired.

Thanks for reading.